# breakline is not working for lstlisting package while none option in hyphenat package used

Tags: listings, margins, report, coding, hyphenat

The below code is the tex file content, which has listings package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} % display coding 

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=C++,
    breaklines=true,
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle={\nhttfamily\footnotesize},
    breakatwhitespace=false,    
    frame=shadowbox,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    linewidth=\textwidth,
    columns=flexible,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}



% document starts here...
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{xxx.cpp}

\end{document}
```

the cpp file content for xxx.cpp shown below.

```
 1   //(title name) This Programme gives the ouput for the theory of the Programme gives the ouput for the theory of the Programme gives the ouput for the theory.
 2   #include <iostream>
 3  using namespace std;
 4  int main() {
    
 5  Code goes here...
 
 6     return 0;
 7 }
```

When the `yyy.tex` file runs, the first line of `xxx.cpp` appears outside the right margin. but when i change the option "`none`" to "`htt`" in `hyphenat` package, it gives correct output. but the remaining content of the tex document other than listings, it enables hyphenation.

All i need is, with the `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, i need the first line of cpp occurs within the frame. or any solution which would satisfy my both necessaries that, all the content in my document should be non-hyphenated and first line of .cpp stays within the frame.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: your code doesn't compile, the colors are not defined. Make a real example that can be used for a test.

Comment: now i updated the above code. retry again sir.

Comment: I'm not a sir, I'm a women. Try `\makeatletter\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{\exhyphenpenalty=50 }\makeatother`

Comment: it shows an error says `Missing \begin{document}. \makeatletter\lst@AddToHook{P` . did you get the output without errors maam?

Comment: can anyone answer to my queries. thank you n advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change a penalty before the listing (it works with \lstinputlisting too):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,    
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\makeatletter\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{\exhyphenpenalty=50 }\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
1   //(title name) This Programme gives the ouput for the theory of the Programme gives the ouput for the theory of the 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ulrike. You literally save me :)

Comment: Actually I put your code before listing, that's why I got the error. After placing the code below the `\lstset`, I got the output as expected.

Comment: And one more thing, if possible can you say, where I can learn about `@AddToHook` and all stuffs. It could help me if you say ma'am. And thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: well this isn't trivial, you need to understand a bit about TeX and LaTeX. I found that by looking into the listings and hyphenat code.